# Does CKRecordZoneID need to be unique per user?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Is a CloudKit record zone created per user basis, or does it apply to everyone?

> A `CKRecordZoneID` object uniquely identifies a record zone in a database.

This seems to imply that it's affecting for everyone.

> A record zone ID distinguishes one zone from another by a name string and the ID of the user that created the zone.

However, the fact that the ID appends the owner name, made it sound like it's per user basis?

The reason why I'm asking is I'd like to know if I can create a single RecordZoneID for the app or does it need to be stored per user (in `NSUserDefaults`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that zone names only need to be unique among the other zones in a user's private database.

There's a subtle but important difference between a `CKRecordZoneID` and a zone name.

A `CKRecordZoneID` must be unique across your entire container, but a `CKRecordZoneID` is more than just the zone name.

If you look at `CKRecordZoneID` you'll see that it has both a `zoneName` property and an `ownerName` property. The `ownerName` is the record ID of the current user (or `CKOwnerDefaultName`, which gets replaced by the real user ID before the value is sent to the server).

The combination of `zoneName` and `ownerName` must be unique across the container, but since every user has their own unique user ID (which is used for `ownerName`) you can create a zone with the same `zoneName` for every user and not have any conflicts.

Comment: does it mean I have to store the `CKRecordZoneID` as part of the user's profile to have access to the Record Zone (say for creating subscription or storing new records)?

Comment: No, you don't need to store the `CKRecordZoneID` anywhere. As far as your app is concerned it just needs to worry about `zoneName` and `ownerName` will always be the current user.

Comment: to ensure multiple installation (across devices logged in to the same icloud) would still write consistently to the same record zones - what should I use for the value of `ownerName`? is `CKOwnerDefaultName` constants consistent across all devices for a given iCloud user?

Comment: You should always use `CKOwnerDefaultName` for the `ownerName` property of a zone. That value gets replaced with the user ID, which is the same for any client logged in to the same iCloud account.